# how to automate checkbox that has label with ::before and ::after and input tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, checkbox, label

Trying to automate

> https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/home/automation

for practice and under section CheckBox & Radio Button practice `Xpath` there is section for "Which automation tools/frameworks do you use?" . These have a list of checkboxes  which I want to automate but they have label with ::before and ::after . Tried `xpath` using input tag `//input[@id='serenity']` but doesn't work.

Tried xpath using input tag `//input[@id='serenity']` but doesn't work.

How do I locate these checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `Serenity BDD` checkbox, Use following `xpath` to identify the element.

```
//label[@for='serenity']
```

To handle dynamic element use explicit wait `WebDriverWait()` and wait for element to be clickable.

```
driver.get("https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/home/automation")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='serenity']"))).click()
```

you need following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Implemented the above suggestions and now it is working fine. Thank you for your help